# Android: an xml that doesn't work properly (framelayout and imageview

Tags: android, include, frame, qr-code

I've this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/head"
/> 
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="200dip" 
android:layout_height="200dip" 
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <include layout="@layout/capture"/>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It must display an image and below a qrcode reader taken from an external apk library created for view the qrcode capture camera.
It only works if i remove the imageviev.
Why?
I need the image and the include.
thanks

Comment: Jack57 is correct, actually LogCat says what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the ImageView more attributes like:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: mmm... uao, so obvious XD
and you know why, if i add:

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

on the java, it crash? i use it for remove the top android bar, but here it doesn't work

Comment: I recommend you ask another question, because I need more information and the formatting in comments is poor.

Comment: i've resolved with the using of the android manifest.
sorry but i don't have the ability to read the logcat in a human way... this is a point i need to study